# python - Lambda Replace

Tags: python, lambda

What other approach can I use instead of 'lambda'

```
def calculate_fees(self):
    return sum(map(lambda x: x.fee, self.bookings.values()))

def calculate_donations(self):
    return sum(map(lambda x: x.donation, self.bookings.values()))

def __str__(self):
    output = 'Event: {0} {1} {2}\n'.format(self.event_id, self.event_date, self.venue) + \
             'Miles: {0}\n'.format(self.miles) + \
             'Max Places: {0}\n'.format(self.max_places) + \
             'Basic Fee: £{0}'.format(self.basic_fee)

    if self.bookings:
        output += '\nRunners:\n' + \
                  '\n'.join(map(lambda x: '{0} {1}'.format(x.runner_id, x.club_id), self.bookings.values()))
    return output
```

Answer (score 6):

The first occurence of `lambda` could be replaced with a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html):

```
return sum(x.fee for x in self.bookings.values())
```

Similar for the second:

```
return sum(x.donation for x in self.bookings.values())
```

The third:

```
'\n'.join('{0} {1}'.format(x.runner_id, x.club_id) for x in self.bookings.values())
```

Since `sum` and `string.join` can deal with a generator, you can use the generator expression directly as an argument to these functions.

Answer (score 4):

Use a generator:

```
return sum(x.fee for x in self.bookings.values())
```

Generally, generators and comprehensions improve readability, especially if you have to use a `lambda` to make `map` or `filter` work. Moreover, `map` and `lambda` don't play well together performance-wise ([Python List Comprehension Vs. Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)).

Comment: @polku Thx for attention! Updated my answer.